# Meteor api.exports export undefined instead of function

Tags: meteor

I write a package wrapper for Meteorjs.

package.js have this line:

`api.addFiles('my-package.js', 'client');`

that successfully adds global property MyPackage to window object.

MyPackage property is a function.

If I add `api.export(['MyPackage'], 'client');` though, MyPackage on window object becomes undefined instead. Any hints?

*related to https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4105*

Comment: Do you mean `api.export('MyPackage', 'client');` ? I'm not sure if the first argument can be an array.

Comment: It doesn't work as a string either. Initially I tried with string but switched to array as an experiment. It can be an array though, saw it in several packages.

Answer (score 0):

It is work as intended at the moment, as was explained by meteor team. 
Reason was I was using `this` to initialize and assign lib variables, but you don't permitted to do this and assign like `MyLib = {}` (globally without any objects) instead.